# Virtual Inheritance Issues

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

Consider the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Thing {
    std::string name;
    int width, length, height, mass;
    Thing (const std::string& n) : name(n) {}
    Thing (const std::string& n, int w, int l, int h, int m) :
        name(n), width(w), length(l), height(h), mass(m) {}
    void print() const {std::cout << name << ", " << width << ", " << length << ", " << height << ", " << mass << '\n';}
    virtual void foo() = 0;  // Abstract class
};

struct Clone : virtual Thing {
    Thing& parent;
    Clone (const std::string& name, Thing& p) : Thing(name), parent(p) {}
};

template <typename T>
struct ClonedType : public Clone, public T {
    ClonedType (const std::string& name, Thing& t) :
        Thing(name), Clone(name, t), T(name) {}
};

// virtual inheritance needed because of ClonedType<Blob> being instantiated:
struct Blob : virtual Thing {
    Blob (const std::string& name) : Thing(name, 3, 4, 5, 20) {}
    virtual void foo() override {}
};

int main() {
    Blob blob("Blob");
    ClonedType<Blob> b("New Blob", blob);
    blob.print();  // Blob, 3, 4, 5, 20
    b.print();  // New Blob, -1, -1, 4237013, 0  // Here's the problem!
}
```

`Blob`'s constructor calls up `Thing`'s constructor fine because of virtual inheritance, but because of that virtual inheritance `ClonedType<T>` fails to call up `Thing`'s constructor through use of `T`'s constructor.  As a result, `b`, which is of type `Blob`, is not properly initialized (all Blob objects are to share the same values 3, 4, 5, 20, and other values like strings and special types that I'm not showing here).  So how to fix this problem other than manually setting each of these values in the Blob constructor body (which would defeat the purpose of `Thing(name, 3, 4, 5, 20)`)?  Thing is an abstract class, by the way.

**Update:**
I've added a solution below that works for the above question, but then in that solution I added more complications to this question that leaves the new problem unsolved.

Comment: Have an appropriate copy constructor for `Thing` perhaps?

Comment: What could that copy constructor do that Thing's implicit copy constructor cannot?

Comment: There isn't an _implicit_ copy constructor, as soon you're starting to declare custom constructors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found one working solution, with the added information that `Thing` is abstract (thus making the solution harder and the above solution invalid):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Thing {
    struct PartialData { int width, length, height, mass; };  //**Added
    struct PartialDataTag {};  //**Added
    std::string name;
    int width, length, height, mass;

    Thing() = default;
    Thing (const std::string& n) : name(n) {}
    Thing (const std::string& n, int w, int l, int h, int m) :
        name(n), width(w), length(l), height(h), mass(m) {}
    Thing (const std::string& n, const PartialData& data) :  // ***Added
        name(n), width(data.width), length(data.length), height(data.height), mass(data.mass) {}
    void print() const {std::cout << name << ", " << width << ", " << length << ", " << height << ", " << mass << '\n';}
protected:
    void setUsingPartialData (const PartialData& data) {  // ***Added
        width = data.width;  length = data.length;  height = data.height;  mass = data.mass;
    }
    virtual void foo() = 0;  // Abstract class
};

struct Clone : virtual Thing {
    Thing& parent;
    Clone (const std::string& name, Thing& p) : Thing(name), parent(p) {}
};

template <typename T>
struct ClonedType : public Clone, public T {
    ClonedType (const std::string& name, Thing& t) :
        Thing(name), Clone(name, t), T(PartialDataTag{}) {}  // ***Changed

};

struct Blob : virtual Thing {
    static const PartialData partialData;
    Blob (const std::string& name) : Thing (name, partialData) {}
    Blob (PartialDataTag) {setUsingPartialData(partialData);}  // ***Added
    virtual void foo() override {}
};
const Thing::PartialData Blob::partialData = {3, 4, 5, 20};  // ***Added

int main() {
    Blob blob("Blob");
    ClonedType<Blob> b("New Blob", blob);
    blob.print();  // Blob, 3, 4, 5, 20
    b.print();  // New Blob, 3, 4, 5, 20
}
```

Can anyone think of a better solution?  A lot of new added stuff to make it work, but at least the information `3, 4, 5, 20` is being used only once here.

Right away, I can think of a serious drawback to this solution though.  Suppose another concrete class derived from `Thing` uses a different type of partial data (say {int, int} only for `width` and `mass`), then my solution above won't work for this new class, right?

**Added to the question:**

```
struct Sample : virtual Thing {
    Sample (const std::string& name, int length, int height) :
        Thing(name, 10, length, height, 50) {}
    virtual void foo() override {}
};
```

How to instantiate

```
ClonedType<Sample>
```

and initialize it correctly?  All `Sample` objects shall have width 10 and mass 50.  Oh, and let's suppose furthermore that `Thing` has more std::string data members (also of static value for `Sample`) so that we cannot resort to using templates (e.g. Sample : Data<10, 50>) to define the `Sample` class.

**Update:  Solved!**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Thing {
    struct PartialData { std::string codeName;  int width, length, height, mass; };
    struct PartialDataTag {};
    std::string name, codeName;
    int width, length, height, mass;

    Thing() = default;
    Thing (const std::string& n) : name(n) {}
    Thing (const std::string& n, int l, int h) : name(n), length(l), height(h) {}
    Thing (const std::string& n, const std::string& c, int w, int l, int h, int m) :
        name(n), codeName(c), width(w), length(l), height(h), mass(m) {}
    Thing (const std::string& n, const PartialData& data) :
        name(n), codeName(data.codeName), width(data.width), length(data.length), height(data.height), mass(data.mass) {}
    void print() const {std::cout << name << ", " << codeName << ", " << width << ", " << length << ", " << height << ", " << mass << '\n';}
protected:
    void setUsingPartialData (const PartialData& data) {
        codeName = data.codeName;  width = data.width;  length = data.length;  height = data.height;  mass = data.mass;
    }
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct Clone : virtual Thing {
    Thing& parent;
    template <typename... Args>
    Clone (Thing& p, Args&&... args) : Thing (std::forward<Args>(args)...), parent(p) {}
};

template <typename T>
struct ClonedType : public Clone, public T {
    template <typename... Args>
    ClonedType (Thing& t, Args&&... args) : Thing (std::forward<Args>(args)...), Clone(t, std::forward<Args>(args)...), T(PartialDataTag{}) {}
};

struct Blob : virtual Thing {
    static const PartialData partialData;
    Blob (const std::string& name) : Thing (name, partialData) {}
    Blob (PartialDataTag) {setUsingPartialData(partialData);}
    virtual void foo() override {}
};
const Thing::PartialData Blob::partialData = {"Bob", 3, 4, 5, 20};  // !

struct Sample : virtual Thing {
    static const int staticWidth = 10, staticMass = 50;
    Sample (const std::string& name, int length, int height) : Thing(name, "Sam", staticWidth, length, height, staticMass) {}
    Sample (PartialDataTag) {setUsingPartialData(getPartialData());}
    virtual void foo() override {}
    PartialData getPartialData() const {return {"Sam", staticWidth, length, height, staticMass};}  // !
};

int main() {
    Blob blob("Blob");
    ClonedType<Blob> b(blob, "New Blob");
    blob.print();  // Blob, Bob, 3, 4, 5, 20
    b.print();  // New Blob, Bob, 3, 4, 5, 20

    Sample sample("Sample", 11, 12);
    ClonedType<Sample> s(sample, "New Sample", 21, 22);
    sample.print();  // Sample, Sam, 10, 11, 12, 50
    s.print();  // Sample, Sam, 10, 21, 22, 50
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you initialize `Thing()` within `Clone` by calling `Thing(name)`. Once initialized once, the constructor is not going to be called a second time.

I don't think that virtual inheritance is really what you are looking for in your case. You probably want to create a separate `Thing` object and not inherit it, but have it as a member.

Comment: Is there no solution while keeping the virtual inheritance?  I already have it this way in my program.

Answer (score 0):

For `virtual` base objects the most derived class is the one which is responsible to call the `virtual` base's constructor. The calls to the `virtual` base `Thing` from intermediate classes are simply ignored. There is no way way around that. That is, the question becomes: how can some intermediate class arrange for the most derived class to call `Thing` with appropriate parameters?

Give that your `Thing` happens to be concrete, one potential approach could be the creation of a temporary `Thing` by some base class, e.g., in `Blob` and have the further derived class get hold of it to pass that to the `Thing` constructor, e.g.:

```
template <typename T>
ClonedType<T>::ClonedType(std::string const& name)
    : Thing(T::get_initializer(name))
    , Clone(name)
    , T(name) {
}
```

Of course, this implies that, e.g., `Blob` has a suitable `static` method `get_initializer()`:

```
auto Blob::get_initializer(std::string const& name) -> Thing {
    return Thing(name, 3, 4, 5, 20);
}
```

Although I think this would make the initialization work I'd generally question the design: typically have a `virtual` base already indicates trouble. If it is essentially stateless and has just a few abstract function it *may* be reasonable. Of course, I'm highly suspicious of any use of the `virtual` keyword: it is rarely useful.

Comment: My `Thing` class is abstract in my program. `Blob` is the highest concrete class in the hierarchy.

Comment: Then you'll need to give it a constructor from a suitable auxiliary object which is then obtained from `get_initializer()`. The usual computer science approach applies: you'll solve your problem by adding another level of indirection.

Comment: Ok, I posted a solution using some indirection.  Is it something along the lines of what you meant by "adding another level of indirection"?